# React unit test - Enzyme Internal Error: unknown node with tag 2

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
<StateProvider initialState={context.initialState} reducer={context.reducer}>
                <div className="search-result">
                    <SearchBox />
                    <React.Suspense fallback={<Loader />}> <SearchPage /> </React.Suspense>
                </div>
            </StateProvider>
```

Iam trying to write the jest unit test for the Search Page component. Getting the below error

```
Enzyme Internal Error: unknown node with tag 2

      53 |         // }
      54 |
> 55 |         component = mount(
     |                     ^
  56 |             <StateProvider initialState={context.initialState} reducer={context.reducer}>
  57 |                 {/* <SearchPage /> */}
  58 |                 <React.Suspense fallback={<Loader />}> <SearchPage /> </React.Suspense>

  at map (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:262:13)
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at childrenToTree (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:277:27)
  at map (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:235:14)
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at childrenToTree (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:277:27)
```

Need help to resolve this issue.